# Turkey getting weapons from Russia

Tags: armed-conflict, turkey, weapons

Why hasn't Turkey been penalized for buying missiles from Russia, despite the fact it is a member of NATO? And is Turkey planning to invade other countries with these weapons?

Comment: Who says it hasn't been penalized? They were dropped from the F-35 program etc.

Comment: I think these are two separate questions and should be posted separately. They're related, but not related enough that you can't answer one without answering the other.

Comment: @Fizz I think the OP says it.   Correcting a misconception should be a perfectly valid way to answer a question.

Comment: "is Turkey planning to invade other countries with these weapons?" Yes, they invaded North Iraq.

Answer (score 5):

- The question of invading "with" or "without" those weapons is naive. Either Turkey invades a country with their armed forces, or it does not. Even if they leave a specific system in the home garrison, it would still be available at need.
- Turkey has intervened in other countries. A key motivation was when those countries *failed* to keep their Kurdish minority under control. SAMs like the [S-400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-400_missile_system) are not commonly used in counterinsurgency operations, but they might be used to assure air superiority in contested border areas.
- The rest of NATO has been quite unhappy with Turkey for several years. But NATO lacks an effective mechanism to expel an unpopular member, and even if they could do it the unhappiness with Turkey might not have reached that point.
  For NATO, Turkey is both a vulnerable flank and a flanking position in the middle east. Countering Iran would be much harder without Turkey.